# Trying to assign a value in a nested struct does not work

Tags: c

I am trying to use a nested struct to represent some data that I am going to write to a file, but when I try to assign the value of the third data member and on, the value does not get assigned. Example:

```
typedef struct {
    short numFields;
    char *datasetID;
    double month;
    double day;
} TestHeader;

typedef struct {

    TestHeader header;

} TestFile;

int main()
{

    TestFile* lre = malloc(sizeof(TestFile));

    lre->header.numFields = 2;
    lre->header.datasetID = "BLAHBLAH";
    lre->header.month = 5.0;
    lre->header.day = 6.0;

    printf("%d, %s, %d, %d\n", lre->header.numFields, lre->header.datasetID, lre->header.month, lre->header.day);
}
```

Output is:

> 2, BLAHBLAH, 0, 0

Why?

Comment: Because you print `double` with `%d`.

Comment: char* does not allocate any storage.  Your code only (partly) works for the string because you assigned it to a string constant.  Which should have given you a warning since that is const.  If you want an element that manages its own storage use std::string

Comment: @DaveS In [tag:c] there is no warning, unlike [tag:c++]. In fact, a string literal is not const, it's read only. C++ enforces their constness to prevent modifying it but you always have `const_cast<>` which will anyway allow you to do it.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi  ah, right, I use C++ at work.  The access violations if you modify it will be a pleasant surprise!

Comment: If you had used your debugger, you would have found out the the assignment worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Because you have used the wrong `printf()` specifier, try

```
printf("%d, %s, %f, %f\n",
    lre->header.numFields, 
    lre->header.datasetID, 
    lre->header.month, 
    lre->header.day
);
```

Also, be careful with the assignment of a *string literal* to a `char` pointer like that, string literals are read only and the pointer to it doesn't reflect that, so you could accidentally try and modify it causing undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't plan on ever changing it. How do you suggest that I store that? char[]?

Comment: @Jared `const char *`

Comment: What do you mean? It depends. Your data structures should reflect what they are for explicitly. So you need to think about that. Do you mean that you wont make it `const`? Then you have to `strdup()` it and be careful to `free()` the pointer later. If their nature is *const*, i.e. they will not change in the course of the program's execution, just make it `const`. Note that `const` is a qualifier and it doesn't imply anything major other than the compiler warning you that you shall not modify that.

Comment: Sorry I mean the value will never change. Sounds like const char * is the way to go. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

First, you must include the relevant header files as you use two standard library functions, namely `malloc()` and `printf()`.

Second, you must use the correct format specifiers for the corresponding arguments of the function `printf()`; `%hd` for short, and `%f` for double.

And lastly, don't forget to free dynamically allocated memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    short numFields;
    char *datasetID;
    double month;
    double day;
} TestHeader;

typedef struct {
    TestHeader header;
} TestFile;

int main()
{
    TestFile* lre = malloc(sizeof(TestFile));

    lre->header.numFields = 2;
    lre->header.datasetID = "BLAHBLAH";
    lre->header.month = 5.0;
    lre->header.day = 6.0;

    printf("%hd, %s, %f, %f\n", lre->header.numFields, lre->header.datasetID, lre->header.month, lre->header.day);

    free(lre);
}
```